# Continuously change value of UILabel on thumb image of UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uislider, addsubview

I have a `UISlider`(min 1 ,max 10). I want its thumb to have a `UILabel` placed on top of it that continuously updates and changes its text on moving the `UISlider`'s thumb. So, I grabbed thumb image from the `UISlider` and added a `UILabel` to it but the label seems to overwrite itself without erasing the previous value once the thumb is moved.

```
- (IBAction)SnoozeSliderValueChanged:(id)sender {

    UIImageView *handleView = [_snoozeSlider.subviews lastObject];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:handleView.bounds];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.snoozeSlider.value];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [handleView addSubview:label];

}
```

Initially,

[image]

Then, when i start dragging,

[image]

I want the label to erase the previous value and show current value as the thumb is moved. Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: With initially, do you mean after you actually touched the slider for the first time? Because initially, meaning after creating the `UISlider`, it has no subviews so this method does not work for me for creating a label before the slider is actually touched for the first time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code continuously adds new subviews. Remove the existing subviews with:

```
[handleView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Alternatively, reuse the existing label. Perhaps using a tag and `viewWithTag:` to find the existing label and update (or create if not found). Reuse is more efficient than recreation.

Answer (score 7):

```
    - (IBAction)SnoozeSliderValueChanged:(id)sender {

        //Get the Image View
        UIImageView *handleView = [_snoozeSlider.subviews lastObject];

        // Get the Slider value label
        UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[handleView viewWithTag:1000];

        // If the slider label not exist then create it and add it to the Handleview. So handle view will have only one slider value label, so no more memory issues & not needed to remove from superview.
        // Creation of object is Pain to iOS. So simply reuse it by creating only once.
        // Note that tag setting below, which will helpful to find out that view presents in later case
        if (label==nil) {

            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:handleView.bounds];

            label.tag = 1000;

            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

            [handleView addSubview:label];


        }

        // Update the slider value
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.snoozeSlider.value];

    }
```

Comment: Check the updated code with description. which will improve your performance rather than the removefromsuperview method

Comment: Clear! But once i go to some other view and return back to this view, i noticed that UILabel doesnt get initialised again and as usual the label tries to update itself. Weird thing is when i log the label,i notice the label value changes as it is supposed to but the label in the running app doesnt change anymore

Comment: try @"%.0f" instead of @"%0.0f"

Answer (score 2):

This is because, on each slider value changed event, you are creating new `UILabel` instance and adding this to view. You can just create the `UILabel` once and on subsequent calls, just update the label frame and label text like below:

```
UIImageView *handleView = [_snoozeSlider.subviews lastObject];
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[handleView viewWithTag:10];

if (!label) { //Create new instance

    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];       
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.tag = 10; //Assign a tag so that you can get the instance from parentview next time
    [handleView addSubview:label];
}
[label setFrame:handleView.bounds]; 
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.snoozeSlider.value];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Swift Class for similar purpose. Its name is [MBSliderView](https://bitbucket.org/s1lent_warrior/mbsliderview-swift/src/da4d5610156bea011cd7671b0daa3fee5b431a35/MBSliderView_Swift/MBSlider/MBSliderView.swift?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
It can be used both in storyboard and from code.

It has 2 display modes for displaying current slider value.
In normal state, it shows value inside thumb like this:  [image]

And when thumb is pressed, it displays the current value like this:  [image]

From code it can be used like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sliderFromCode = MBSliderView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // configure sliderFromCode
        sliderFromCode.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 100)
        sliderFromCode.minValue = 0
        sliderFromCode.maxValue = 10
        sliderFromCode.currentValue = 3
        sliderFromCode.step = 1
        sliderFromCode.ignoreDecimals = true   // default value
        sliderFromCode.animateLabel = true      // default value
        sliderFromCode.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(sliderFromCode)
    }
}
```

and in order to receive the slider value, you must implement the `MBSliderDelegate`. Something like this:

```
extension ViewController: MBSliderDelegate {
    func sliderView(_ sliderView: MBSliderView, valueDidChange value: Float) {
        print("sliderFromCode: \(value)")
    }
}
```

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/s1lent_warrior/mbsliderview-swift/get/da4d5610156b.zip) is the complete sample code.

I know its very to late to answer, but hope this helps you or someone else

Comment: There was no swift then :/

Comment: @motox its in swift!