# UISlider no subviews in ViewDidLoad()

Tags: swift, uilabel, uislider

I want to put a `UILabel` on the `UISlider`'s thumb.

My code is based on this: [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372981/continuously-change-value-of-uilabel-on-thumb-image-of-uislider)

The problem is that with that code, there's no text on the thumb before you change the value. So I made a few modifications. I made the label a global variable and I configure it in `viewDidLoad()`. Then I just change the text when the slider changes value.

The ACTUAL problem is this(code in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
let thumbView = mySlider.subviews.last
label.frame = (thumbView?.bounds)!
```

`mySlider`'s `subviews` array is empty. Therefore it creates a crash since I unwrap a nil value.

I don't understand why that happens since the view is fully initialized.

Why is `mySlider.subviews` empty? What am I missing? Does anyone know how can I fix this? Is there any other way of placing the label in the middle of the thumb?

Comment: Your view is fully initialized but your slider's subviews not necessarily. The thumbView is likely lazily instantiated, so it has not been created in `viewDidLoad` because it has not be called yet. You should use @Zac Kwan suggestion to avoid having to manipulate the slider's view hierarchy directly.

Comment: @beyowulf Would there be a way to force initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mySlider.subviews.last` is not a reliable method to get the center of the thumbImage. It wasn't mention anywhere in the docs. I personally think is quite hacky to do it that way.

However, to get the center of the `slider` you could calculate base on the `value` of the `slider` using a combine of `trackRectForBounds` and `thumbRectForBounds`.

This should work for you:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(slider: UISlider) {
    let trackRect = slider.trackRectForBounds(slider.bounds)
    let thumbRect = slider.thumbRectForBounds(slider.bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: slider.value)

    sliderLabel.center = CGPointMake(thumbRect.origin.x + thumbRect.size.width / 2 + slider.frame.origin.x, slider.frame.origin.y + thumbRect.size.height / 2)
}
```

Basically what this does is to first compute the rect of the track then use it to compute the thumbRect. Lastly set the center taking into consideration the width and height of the slider and thumb size.

Do remember to set your `label` text alignment to center.

Comment: It does make sense but it doesn't work. I put your code in `viewDidLoad()` for the initial value and in a function for when the value changes. The problems are that: 1. The label is a bit above the thumb. 2. The label doesn't move if I change the value.

Comment: I fiddled with it a bit and I managed to make the label stay on the thumb(I had modified the slider previously to work in steps/snap to values), but it's still higher than the thumb and it's really weird. I have another slider where the thumb is modified to be 160x30pts and the label is left to the slider's x origin.

Comment: This does nothing to solve the OP's question, all it does is is replace one hack for getting the center with another one. The label will still not display after the slider is loaded in the `viewDidLoad()` method, which is what the OP (and I) are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The code from [your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372981/continuously-change-value-of-uilabel-on-thumb-image-of-uislider) works fine, no need to change that.

Add this method and the initial value will appear as a `UILabel` on your `UISlider`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [mySlider sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ThumbTextSlider: UISlider {
 var thumbTextLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
 var passedValue = 0

 private var thumbFrame: CGRect {
     return thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: trackRect(forBounds: 
  bounds), value: value)
 }

 override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()

     thumbTextLabel.frame = thumbFrame
     thumbTextLabel.text = String(passedValue)
 }

 override func awakeFromNib() {
     super.awakeFromNib()
     addSubview(thumbTextLabel)
     setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon-settings"), for: .normal)
     thumbTextLabel.font = UIFont(name: "SFProText-Semibold", size: 16)
     thumbTextLabel.textAlignment = .center
     thumbTextLabel.layer.zPosition = layer.zPosition + 1
 }
}
```